# RESTful Web Services Publishing API

Tags: web-services, rest, jakarta-ee

I am developing a RESTful Web Service that performs CRUD operations. Is there a way to publish an API for my data object XMLs?

There's the WADL that describes services but nothing (that I know of) to tell the consumer what the service expects or returns as XML data object.

Is there a common practice to publish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We provide xsd schemas and examples for both request and response in the documentation pages. The REL can point to these documentation pages. Here is an example using HAL that has a place holder for the documentation. We also provide additional link relations. We also provide business description for the resouce

http://hal-shop.heroku.com/hal_browser.html#/